# Eclipse Kepler: how to export RCP product as an executable jar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I just started using Eclipse Kepler.  From the Overview tab I'm able to select 'Eclipse Product export wizard' which generates an executable (.exe) that can be executed from the command line. 
How can I export the product as an executable .jar that can be executed from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse RCPs are always executable `.exe` files (or the equivalent on other platforms), there is no option to create a Jar file.

Eclipse code contains platform specific components so you have to do a different build for each platform.

If you want to generate code to run on Linux, Mac OS X or the other supported platforms you need to check the `Export for multiple platforms` option on the product export page and select the platforms on the next page of the wizard.

You will need to install the `RCP Delta Pack` to build for multiple platforms.

Update: The Export wizard is now deprecated. [tycho](/questions/tagged/tycho) and [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) is now the recommened way to build RCPs.

See [Eclipse Products and Deployment](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no option to export your product as an executable .jar, you can start your application without using the executable (.exe). All the executable does is show the splash screen, load a JVM and start the Equinox launcher which is an executable .jar.

You can start the Equinox launcher from the command line yourself with the command `java -jar plugin\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_<version>.jar` which will start the application (without the splash screen of course).

The Eclipse wiki has [launcher scripts](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Starting_Eclipse_Commandline_With_Equinox_Launcher) that make it easier to deal with the version part of the plugin name.

This will however not make the application launch on other platforms as it still contains platform specific plugins. See [greg-449's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21495446/3104218) on how to export for multiple platforms if that's what you want to do.